# Game - using front camera with openCV face detection

Tags: java, android, opencv, libgdx

I need to write application/game on Android. What I need is face detection ( mouth + optionally eyes). I already wrote face detection part, but now I need to start second part, game. Before I wrote some games in LibGDX, but I dont know, how I can merge that two libraries (if it is possible).
Have u any idea what I need to do ? Maybe u know any simple game engine that will cooperate with opencv ? Or any other ideas, how I can do that?

Already i have method: compare(), which returns:
- 1 - when someone open mouth
- 2 - when someone close eyes
That part working fine, but i dont have idea how i can use it in OpenCV library to make simple game.
I tried by (that code should represents player):

```
Rect a = new Rect(0,10,0,10);
Core.rectangle(mRgba, a.tl(), a.br(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 2);
if(compare()==1)a.x++;
```

and others, but it is too crude.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

---

```
package com.saper;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;

public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = false;

    initialize(new Saper(), cfg);
}
}
```

This is all code from -android folder. In folder with game i have tons of files and wall of code. 
The problem here is: Where i need to add this part from opencv?

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe u know any simple game engine that will cooperate with opencv ?

Any Game Engine should do that. What you need to do is use your Method in the main loop of your game. This way you can use the user input (output from `compare()`) to do stuff in every iteration of your main game loop.

Since I don´t know what kind of game you want to make I can´t help you with deciding which Engine would do the best Job.

You may find useful information in one of this Threads:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752930/getting-started-with-game-development
http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/how-do-i-start-java-game-development/27156/view.html
https://www.udemy.com/blog/java-game-programming/

Comment: I want to make a platform game, where hero run automatically from left side to right, and player can (open mouth) to jump, and (close eyes) to hide from enemy. Still dont know if scene will be static and hero will move, or hero will be in center of screen and scene will be dynamic.

Comment: I prefer LibGDX, because i wrote some games in it already. But i dont know how i can "merge" this two libraries together. How main activity should look like ? Because from one hand i have main_activity from opencv/android, and in other i have from libgdx which is divided to 3 folders (with game, -android, -desktop), and the problem is, in which part i need to add this ? I cant add this to that folder with game because there isnt any android libraries, which are in folder with -android in name.

Comment: @Alca hi, did you make your game? If you managed to do this, can you share with your experience?